# django cms administration https cross origin frame

Tags: https, django-admin, cross-domain, django-cms

```
django-cms==3.4.2  
server=nginx   
security=https://letsencrypt.org/
```

Since my web site is on https I'm unable to access django admin pages directly from my site (www.blabla.ab)

I can access them by changing the url while adding admin at the end or the url https://blabla.ab/fr/admin but not thought the admin cms dropdown menu (top left part of the window) or double click menu, I get the following error:

> SecurityError : Failed to read the ‘contentDocument’ property from ‘HTMLIFrameElement’ : Blocked a frame 
>   With origin “https” from accessing a **cross-origin** frame

or at form popup:

> The form could not be loaded. Please check that the server is running.

It seems that Django CMS admin does not work with https because of cross-origin frame?
I've tried with

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM https://blabla.ab/'
```

with the django security middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
```

but it does'nt change anything. Any idea?

Comment: It is ok I've found the problem. My vhost.conf file located in /etc/nginx/sites-available was pointing on a ssl params file

`include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;`

and in that ssl-params.conf file I had the followinf line
`add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;`

I've changed that line to
`add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;`

Comment: Please post that as an answer to the question so future visitors can see it better.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause of the problem.

My vhost.conf file located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` was pointing on a ssl params file include `/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf`

and in that `ssl-params.conf` file I had the following line

```
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
```

I've changed that line to

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```